# iPad versions of Chat broken

Tags: support, chat, ipad

*The bugs do not cover main -site, only chat. I use the Apple Wireless Bluetooth -keyboard.*

[image]

**iPad Google Chrome (mobile version and desktop version have bugs)**

> - page fluctuates up-down-up-...-down and the layout breaks up every-now-then (very hard reading)
> - @robTAB does not auto-complete to @robjohn (impossible to type certain names of people)
> - up down -keys do not work: they do not show your last messages to do edit, JS disabled?
>
> > [image]
>
> - etc
>
> The latter was with the Desktop -version. The mobile version for iPad is even poorer.

**Safari**

> I cannot find a desktop version for this but auto-completion not working, have not tested everything.

Please, fix the iPad versions of the chat. Discussion [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6433995#6433995).

Comment: We don't support the mobile version of Chrome at the moment. The mobile version of the chat doesn't do tab auto-completion (most mobile devices don't even have a Tab key), but you can try if the desktop version works out for you (tap on "menu", then "full site").

Comment: @balpha no as I said, the Desktop -version does not work in iPad, under iPad Google Chrome. It is called `"Request Desktop site"`.

Comment: You can ask chat for the desktop site without changing your user agent. Again, tap on "menu", then "full site".

Comment: @balpha I tried but auto-comp and other things not working in chat, auto-comp works in main site.